# Florida Home Renting - Can my lease forbid repairing my vehicle?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, florida

I received a letter by my landlord today stating that I have 7 days to vacate or remedy the situation - the situation being that I replaced the alternator I suppose in my car the other day?

The title of the letter states "Seven Day Notice of Non-Compliance (With Opportunity To Cure) stating "As per the section titled vehicles which states: 'Tenant is not to repair or disassemble vehicles on the premises'"

I'm not even totally sure how I'm supposed to go about remedying this as it's not something that's ongoing, but I'm also surprised that that's a rule in my lease, is there really absolutely no way I'm allowed to fix my own car?

Comment: Why are you surprised? If it's in the lease you signed then surely you read it? Giving you notice to remedy something which is in the past and not still ongoing is rather strange though. I would have expected some other sort of notice of violation and possibly a penalty or warning that if it happens again you'd be evicted.

Comment: I signed it 4 years ago, not that it would nullify something I signed, but every aspect of the lease isn't fresh in my mind, especially not that rule, but 4 years ago I also wouldn't have replaced a component of my car myself, either, so it seems like a ridiculous rule now, but not so much then

Comment: I wouldn't sweat it. I don't think they intend to be hard on you, I think it is just saying don't do it again in a formal way.

Comment: I believe this is actually a common clause in HOA's CCRs, and even in some city by-laws.

Comment: What's considered "repair or disassemble" exactly? Would this include things like an oil change as well?

Comment: If the car is now reassembled (and disassembled old part is not present), notify them you cured the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you signed the lease, technically you agreed to it so you can't really object now. Yeah, it is a little ridiculous.

I think, if you really went to court a judge would have leniency on you, but he/she might not, as well.

Try to talk to them and see what the "opportunity to cure" is.

Comment: I plan on just driving the car in question to their offices tomorrow to show that it's obviously functioning, hopefully they can shed some light on why the left the letter at my door (although I do believe the neighbors across the street are the head of the HOA, so maybe this is their doing)

Comment: (the HOA company is also the same company as the rental agents)

Comment: Yeah, its probably a form letter type thing right? I really doubt they would be that extreme over fixing the car. It's probably more of a this is against the rules thing.

Comment: Yeah it looks like a vague letter with blanks that are hand written in from, the template looks like it came from some random law firm